# An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: apache, tomcat, struts2, akamai, big-ip

Some users experience difficulty logging into our web site and got the following error message.

An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.64bcf648.1412893809.36fcbfb4

They said that they could sometimes log　in but sometimes couldn't do.

I and my co-workers tried to do it a lots, but We didn't get any errors.
The users said that they removed all of cookies and caches.

We are using apache, tomcat, struts2, akamai(CDN),big-ip.

What's happening with our web site?

Comment: It must be some kind of bug

Comment: Do you know how to find the reason for the bug?

Comment: Noone can answer a question like this. For a more appropriate answer, please write a more appropriate question

Comment: OK.I will gather more information from the users and log files.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this Q&A. I had seen from Googling it was related to Akamai already too - currently experiencing it accessing http://codeguru.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found Akamai(CDN) returned the error pages because our server returned 504 errors.

Answer (score -2):

just try ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew from the command line prompt. Post your comments if it works or not